# How do I paint an airplane with an electrostatic paint gun?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I have a Cessna 150 which needs a paint job. As I have experience in painting objects with a spray can, and also in stripping airplanes, I am thinking to paint the Cessna myself.

What are the considerations required for this job? I would enjoy the experience and I'm able to get it prepped and ready. What would be a good electrostatic paint machine for this job? And how can I practice before painting the aircraft?

---

Note, I know the paints are different, I've heard of something called Imron, as well as Epoxy paints that harden and set.  Suggestions on that would be welcome too.

Comment: Paint on an airplane needs to be relatively thin, since an A/C has a large surface area and weight is an issue. It also needs to be tough because of the aggression of relative wind, UV light, and even mechanical due to debris thrown up by the engines. All these factors are quite different from what is needed in home painting. I would suggest migrating this question to Aviation SE, where there are people quite knowledgeable on this topic and who will no doubt set you on your path.

Comment: I'd check out the EAA for resources. There will probably be a local chapter and tons of folks with experience building metal aircraft. I wager most do not paint themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I am a retired aircraft painter.

For electrostatic painting: ensure that the aircraft is grounded; ensure that you are grounded to the gun; use compatible electrostatic paint, this is a must.

My suggestion is, unless you are greatly concern about overspraying, to use a normal system on small aircraft, such as suction fed or gravity fed, as it will do the same job. Application is the same for all systems.

Hope this helps